# AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values when use dataframe to deal time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

The data in test.csv likes this:

```
device_id,upload_time
id1,2020-06-01 07:46:30+00:00
id2,2020-06-05 16:04:32+00:00
```

When I use this code to add column of dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'E:/test.csv',parse_dates=[1], encoding='utf-8')
df['new_upload_time'] = df['upload_time'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8) #add 8 hours
df['new_upload_time'] = df['new_upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df['upload_time_year_month'] = df['new_upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')
df.to_csv(r'E:/result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)
```

The error message is:

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this statement:

`df['new_upload_time'] = df['new_upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

When you run the above, you convert `datetime` column to `object`. So, when you use `.dt` it fails.

You can just change the order of the statements like this and it will work:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'E:/test.csv',parse_dates=[1], encoding='utf-8')
df['new_upload_time'] = df['upload_time'] + pd.Timedelta(hours=8) #add 8 hours
df['upload_time_year_month'] = df['new_upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')
df['new_upload_time'] = df['new_upload_time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.to_csv(r'E:/result.csv', index=False, mode='w', header=True)
```